# extjs - what event/method is fired/called when button loses focus?

Tags: extjs

I want to know what event/method is fired/called when a button loses focus/blurs in extjs.

I have a button with a menu. When I click anywhere other than the button or menu items then the menu closes. So what I want to know is what calls menu.hide() method so that menu hides.

Does anyone have any idea about this? I tried onBlur for button but it is not fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  @mankz. Just override `onMouseDown()` function in `Ext.menu.MenuMgr`. Although, to do this I had to redefine the `Ext.menu.MenuMgr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * Try to focus this component.
     * @param {Boolean} selectText (optional) If applicable, true to also select the text in this component
     * @param {Boolean/Number} delay (optional) Delay the focus this number of milliseconds (true for 10 milliseconds)
     * @return {Ext.Component} this
     */
    focus : function(selectText, delay){
        if(delay){
            this.focusTask = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(this.focus, this, [selectText, false]);
            this.focusTask.delay(Ext.isNumber(delay) ? delay : 10);
            return this;
        }
        if(this.rendered && !this.isDestroyed){
            this.el.focus();
            if(selectText === true){
                this.el.dom.select();
            }
        }
        return this;
    },

    // private
    blur : function(){
        if(this.rendered){
            this.el.blur();
        }
        return this;
    },
```

Interesting. Apparently ExtJS does not raise any event when a `Component` get the focus nor when it lose it. Probably it deserves an override.

Comment: hi thanks a lot for replying. I overridded Component's blur method to print (using console.log()) but it doens't print anything. it means it doesn't goes there. Any ideas? Regards

Comment: Strange. It means that the blur function is called programmatically somewhere by ExtJS; it's not invoked automatically from browser activity. With Firebug, check what that "el" in "this.el.blur()" is referring to. You should find a way to attach the onblur eventHandler on it.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS Button has an event named `menuhide` for this exact purpose. It is fired when the menu attached to a button (assuming there is one) is hidden. The event is called with arguments `(Button this, Menu menu)`.

See [ExtJS API documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Button) for more details - button events `menushow`, `menutriggerout`, `menutriggerover`, and `mouseout` might also prove useful.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. Actually I want to hide menu on a condition. For this i m returning false (using a variable) from beforehide method of menu. What i want to do is if somebody clicks outside of button & menu then always close the menu. So i think i am looking for some other method. Regards.

Comment: So you're preventing the menu from hiding by yourself, by always returning false from beforehide event of menu - Why? Which cases of menu hiding are you trying to prevent?